# How to move a tag?

Tags: mercurial, vcs-tags

I want to start using tags in Mercurial. I plan to have a "stable" tag that always points to the last good revision.

As I understand it, I can tag the current changeset via `hg tag stable`.

**What's the proper way to move the tag?** When I try to run `hg tag stable` again it tells me:

> abort: tag 'stable' already exists (use -f to force)

And if I force it, I get [this bug](http://mercurial.808500.n3.nabble.com/Bug-3589-New-quot-hg-tag-f-quot-to-move-existing-tag-results-in-a-duplicate-entry-of-the-old-tag-td3991780.html) which has no resolution or comments. i.e., it duplicates the old tag. I don't even know why the tag needs to be in there more than once in the first place; I just want to update it to point to a single changeset.

Comment: Looks like this is [intended behaviour](http://selenic.com/pipermail/mercurial/2012-May/042762.html). Weird.

Comment: You linked to an automatic post on the mailinglist when the bug was submitted. The current status is [in Bugzilla](http://bz.selenic.com/show_bug.cgi?id=3589) "RESOLVED INVALID" and there is a comment explaining why.

Comment: (psst, hey, could you create a wiki for vcs-tags?)

Comment: @Will: I added a little blurb. I'm not an expert on the subject matter nor how they differ across different VCS's, but hopefully that will suffice for now.

Answer (score 16):

I haven't see such tag *move* operation, but it is essentially copying something and removing the original so:

```
hg tag --remove stable
hg tag -r newrevisionhash  stable
```

Or append some sort of suffix to your tags, like a version number. It would also allow you to keep track of your releases.

Opinion 1: I always thought Mercurial was more about preserving history and whereas under git you could change something, in Mercurial you would have to overwrite it instead.

Opinion 2: another alternative to marking stable releases would be to keep them in one branch. Where I work `default` holds only stable code. All other work is done in isolated branches.

A dirty one-liner to update a tag:

```
current=`hg log -l1 --template '{node}'`; hg tag --remove stable; hg tag -r $current stable
```

It seems that this atrocity can even be added as a Mercurial alias in `.hgrc`:

```
[alias]
movetag=!(current=`hg log -l1 --template '{node}'`; $HG tag --remove stable; $HG tag -r $current stable)
```

I capture the value of current tip, as tag removal/adding are commits in themselves, so they 'move' tip along (can't see anything wrong about tagging `tip` -- it's for precision sake only). There's certainly potential to make it prettier, but those worked for me.

Comment: Regarding option 2, that's essentially what we do. All work is done on other branches, but we merge them into default when they're ready and then perform integration testing. There's a period where 'default' may be fubar if there's a bad merge. Thus I want to keep a stable tag on default and only move it after the integration testing is complete/verified.

Comment: Version number wouldn't work. That'd be a major PITA. I want everyone to update to 'stable' before starting to work on a new issue; can't have them constantly looking up the latest version number. The version numbers could compliment it, but I need one that always refers to the latest.

There must be some sort of common practice for this. Is it better to always remove the tag, or just have dozens of the same tag in there? Actually, "remove" doesn't actually remove anything. It just adds a dummy record to `.hgtags`, and then when you add a new one, it duplicates the dummy tag as always.

Comment: Well it's no longer listed in eg. `log` output, so it does something. And like I said -- maybe keeping track of everything is just 'mercurial way'. I don't think it's ever caused me trouble. As to version numbers: I've seen a project where the deployment date was suffixed to tag name (if it went well) -- kinda redundant, but it was convenient for the developers.

Comment: Mercurial's wiki states 3 ways of removing a tag and the third one might be of interest to you: *removing all references to tagname in .hgtags (but this might confuse the multiple-head tag collision resolution algorithm)* (http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tag).

Comment: I don't think deleting all references in `.htags` will actually kill the tag anyway. It still shows up when I run `hg tags`. I guess I'll just keep forcing it, as that seems to be the easiest and cleanest solution. I really don't like the possibility of upping to the wrong version of the tag though.

Comment: I did a little experiment and purged `.hgtags`. It does output tags through `hg tags`, but not after I commit modified `.hgtags`. Then it's only `tip` left. You can try that, but it I wander what would happen when it came to merging stuff afterwards.

Comment: I'm still seeing a tag in `hg tags` even though is absent from `.hgtags` and I've committed and pushed...

Answer (score 6):

Instead of having a tag that moves, you should use named branches instead. They function almost like a moving tag.

You write in a comment above that

> All work is done on other branches, but we merge them into 'default' when they're ready and then perform integration testing. There's a period where 'default' may be fubar if there's a bad merge. Thus I want to keep a stable tag on default and only move it after the integration testing is complete/verified.

To solve this you need an extra named branch — call it `stable`. Then merge tested and approved changesets on `default` into `stable` in your own pace. It doesn't matter if `default` has changesets that are still being tested, when changeset X passes the tests, you do

```
$ hg update stable
$ hg merge X
```

to promote X as a stable changeset. Descendants of X (on `default`) remain unchanged, i.e., they are not yet marked stable.

Comment: I was thinking about this.  I think this solves keeping track of releases, but not giving devs a target to pull and build off of, since now they are building on the 'stable' branch.  They'd need to merge back to default or some such.

Answer (score 4):

As @guessimtoolate and @Martin Geisler already pointed out, you can use a named branch to accommodate all good revisions (which is also the way we use hg at the company). Another way is to use [bookmarks](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Bookmarks), which act as movable labels attached to one revision.